# iOS 7 web app status bar

Tags: html, ios, web-applications, ios7

I'm building an iOS web app. Since updating to iOS 7 I'm noticing the status bar has a number of issues. I'd like to get the status bar to show as white with black text/icons but I can't seem to figure it out.

The meta tags I've tried are:

Shows just an empty black bar and shifts content down:

```
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="default" />
```

Shows a black bar with white text/icons:

```
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black" />
```

Shows a white bar with white text/icons:

```
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black-translucent" />
```

Any ideas about what I'm doing wrong or how to get the status bar to show up as a white background with black text?

Comment: http://www.mobilexweb.com/blog/safari-ios7-html5-problems-apis-review claims that your last one should be OK. Maybe it depends on the background colour of the page?

Comment: If set to `black-translucent`, the status bar is black and translucent.

Answer (score 2):

`"translucent"` does work for iPhones, but it is hit or miss.

You might get lucky by putting some css inside of
 `@media only screen (height: "iPHONES HEIGHTs"px) and (width: 320px) {
 }`.

The only way I got it to work on my iPad is by saving the webpage as `translucent`then changing the webpage to `"black-translucent"` and relaunching the webapp.

7.0.4 came out today and it's still a problem. Come'on Apple :(

Answer (score 2):

> I'm building an iOS web app. Since updating to iOS 7 I'm noticing the status bar has a number of issues. I'd like to get the status bar to show as white with black text/icons but I can't seem to figure it out.

I did it. Here is answer for you.

https://github.com/BYODKM/pwdGen/blob/gh-pages/index.html#L8-L16

Point is; App should be saved with "black-translucent" onto Home Screen, but run with "default".

Comment: Sorry, I deleted the repo for reason. But, using Javascript to change the value of META tag from "black-translucent" to "default" when your WebApp will open from user's homescreen, you can solve this case.

Comment: (function(){
    if (!window.navigator.standalone) {
     var meta = document.createElement("meta");
     meta.setAttribute("name", "apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style");
     meta.setAttribute("content", "black-translucent");
     var head = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
     head.appendChild(meta);
    }
   }());

Answer (score 0):

If you remove this meta line, make your background color white it will show a white status bar.

The browser will take a tint of your body background-color. As far as i checked and notices also for your statusbar. It seems all integrated in the browser frame

Comment: You seem to be correct that the tint of the status bar will match the background of the app. However, no matter what I do, the text is always white. So if the background of the app is white the text is invisible. I've done a bit of a workaround by adding a `<div>` with a colored background to the very top of the app, but this is far from ideal.